# How can you compare equality of two vectors of infinite dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

E.g., say we have 2 vectors of infinite dimension: $$A=<1,0,1,1,...,1>$$$$B=<0,1,1,1,...,1>$$
These are qualitatively *not* the same vector, though it seems hard to definitively prove that.

If you define equality as $A_i=B_i$ for all elements $i$, then it seems to follow that $A\neq B$.

However, if you define equality between vectors as $\Vert A \Vert =\Vert B \Vert$ and $A$ being co-linear and co-directed with $B$, then these vectors might seem equal, as $\Vert A \Vert = \Vert B \Vert = ∞$, and the angle between the two vectors converges upon $0$ at $∞$ (although by the formula $cos \theta=\frac{<A, B>}{\Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert}$, this might technically be indeterminate, I suppose).

Is there a better way to understand and rationalize the relationship between infinite dimension vectors?

Comment: When you say $\| \cdot \|$, you mean a finite number. Here, the "length" of these two vectors is not defined. And in general, equality is defined the first way you mentioned. Two vectors are equal if they are equal at every individual "coordinate".

Comment: It's easy to prove those two vectors aren't the same since the projection onto the first and second coordinate differ, therefore they're different vectors.

Comment: I don't understand why you said it is hard to prove those two vectors are not the same. Before having vector space structure, the space is a set. And two vectors are the same iff they are a same element in the set.

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:infinity] or with [tag:number-theory]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's use a more concrete example to demonstrate this point, which you are probably already quite familiar with.

Consider all the continuous functions defined on the interval $[0,1]$. This is usually notated as $C[0,1]$. Firstly, is this a vector space? The answer is yes

What is the dimension of this space? It is infinite - as you need to define the value of the function at each point in $[0,1]$ - of which there are infinitely many

Now, when are two vectors (functions) from this space equal? When their pointwise match is equal - or in more mathematical terms

$$f = g \space \text{iff} \space \space ||f-g|| = 0$$

where || is a norm function defined on the vector space